# Invoking jQuery methods on DOM elements without using selectors

Tags: jquery, dom

Here's a simple code:

```
 var elements = $('#myDiv').find('a');
```

Let's say elements array contains 5 links. Now I want to hide the zeroeth link in the array like this:

```
$(elements[0]).css("display","none");
```

I know that $(elements[0]) is illegal. I could say:

```
var selector="#"+elements[0].id
```

and then

```
$(selector).css("display","none");
```

But how can I reference that element if no id is assigned to it?

Comment: why should `$(elements[0])` be illegal? If it references a real `DomElement` it will work.

Comment: Why is `$(elements[0])` illegal?

Comment: Hmm, :)). i did not even try that way, don't know why but I thought it was impossible. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to apply special selectors here. To get the first element use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

```
$("#myDiv").find("a:first").hide();
```

or [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$("#myDiv").find("a:eq(0)").hide();
```

where `:eq(0)` selects the element with index 0.

Comment: `elements.eq(0)` performs better though :P

Comment: @Asad This `$("#myDiv a:first")` should work faster because of native `querySelector`.

Comment: @VisioN you mean `:first-child`, `:first` is jQuery (or probably sizzle)

Comment: @VisioN The docs would disagree: `Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first").`

Comment: @Asad I must agree, I forgot that CSS doesn't have `:first` pseudo class.

Comment: @VisioN You could always update your answer to use `:first-child`. As things stand you are suggesting the two least efficient ways of getting the result.

Comment: @Asad In fact I just suggest the way of getting the result but not the most efficient one. There is no question of providing the most efficient answer, agree. Moreover, `:first-child` is not the same as `:first`: they behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

this will work

```
$('#myDiv a:first').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = $('#myDiv').find('a');
elements.filter(':first').css("display","none");
```

or

```
$('#myDiv').find('a:first').css("display","none");
```

or better

```
$('#myDiv a:first:visible').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$(elements[0])` weirds you out, you can use:

```
elements.eq(0)
```

Note however, that performance wise `$(elements[0])` is superior to pretty much any other approach, with `.eq` coming in second (not counting stuff like `$(elements.get(0))`, which is just as likely to weird you out).

I would not recommend using `:first` or `:eq`, since they are by far the slowest.

See this benchmark: http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-vs-first2/6

Comment: @MikeJM But it's the fastest one. See the jsperf benchmark I included.